# gcov C++ - not correctly detecting the filename suffix

Tags: c++, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gcov

I am compiling all my `.cpp` with `-g --coverage` and linking with `--coverage`

When I run my executable, the `.gcda` file is produced.

But when I do `gcov file_test.cpp` it says:

```
$ gcov file_test.cpp
file_test.gcno:cannot open notes file
file_test.gcda:cannot open data file, assuming not executed
No executable lines
```

But the directory contains all the required files

```
$ ls
file_test.cpp  file_test.cpp.gcda  file_test.cpp.gcno  file_test.cpp.o
```

If you look at the `gcov` error, it looks like it's chopping off the `.cpp` from the filename.

What is happening?

If it's relevant, I'm using `cmake` and the `.gcda`, `.gcno` files are produced next to the `.o` file which is in `cmake`'s nested folder structure so I have to copy `file_test.cpp` to that folder and run `gcov`.

Comment: I use `clang` and `llvm-cov`.  Regardless... `clang++ -std=c++17 -O0 -g -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping foo.test.cpp foo.cpp -o foo`, then `LLVM_PROFILE_FILE=foo.profraw ./foo`, then `llvm-profdata merge -sparse ./foo.profraw -o foo.profdata`, then `llvm-cov show -format=html -tab-size=4 ./foo -instr-profile=foo.profdata foo.cpp > foo.html`, then (for pretty-fying) `echo '<style>pre { font-family: Consolas, Monaco, monospace; }</style>' >> foo.html`, and finally `open foo.html`. If your unit tests don't have **coverage**, you've got bubkes.

Comment: @Eljay I compiled all my files with `—coverage`; I checked the build log. The fact that I got `.gcno` for this file during compilation AND `.gcda` was generated when it ran means my compile and link options are correct.